# Why aremy arrays being wrapped when console.log in terminal?

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code

In the terminal of my Mac, If I console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]), the result displayed in the Terminal on multiple lines

```
"[
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
  6, 7, 8, 9, 10
 ] "
```

My expected and desired output is

```
"[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]"
```

all in one line. 
I'm not sure if I inadvertently modified a setting or if that's just how Macs output arrays.
My Windows desktop outputs the array in one line.
I am on MacOS using VS code and node.js. I tried looking at my terminal and VSCode settings to no avail.
Does anyone know why the output is formatted into separate lines?

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5]))`

Comment: @AnujPancholi This workaround works for a 1d array, but if I wanted to output a 2d array like `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]` it would all be in one line as opposed to 2.

Comment: Try importing inspect from the util module like `const inspect = require('util').inspect;` and then try `console.log(inspect(my2dArr,{depth: Infinity}))`